# How to parse JSON Array with different keys on the same level

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have Array and i need to get summ of quantity * price. But the array keys on the third level is different.

I use this PHP code but i only can take price & quantity for first item ['506-p1-8_p2-_p3-']

```
$quantity = $elements['1af7e792-bcff-4a6c-9bdb-dd5023b0251a']['items']['506-p1-8_p2-_p3-'][quantity];
$price = $elements['1af7e792-bcff-4a6c-9bdb-dd5023b0251a']['items']['506-p1-8_p2-_p3-'][price];
$summ = $price*$quantity;
```

How to parse all levels to get Summ = (price * quantity)
Thank to all who can help me

```
Array
(
    [1af7e792-bcff-4a6c-9bdb-dd5023b0251a] => Array
        (
            [is_advance] => 1
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [506-p1-8_p2-_p3-] => Array
                        (
                            [hash] => 506-p1-8_p2-_p3-
                            [sku] => 501
                            [itemId] => 506
                            [quantity] => 6
                            [price] => 80.75
                            [currency] => UAH
                            [priceDesc] => 
                            [priceParams] => Array
                                (
                                    [u0420u0430u0437u043cu0435u0440] => 8
                                )
                            [name] => qwerty
                        )
                    [498-p1-6_p2-_p3-] => Array
                        (
                            [hash] => 498-p1-6_p2-_p3-
                            [sku] => 498
                            [itemId] => 498
                            [quantity] => 5
                            [price] => 500
                            [currency] => UAH
                            [priceDesc] => 
                            [priceParams] => Array
                                (
                                    [u0420u0430u0437u043cu0435u0440] => 6
                                )
                            [name] => qwerty
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Do you want the total price for all items. So every item total added up for a grand total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell how the array is generated in the first place. So just going off of the code you've posted, this should sum up the total for every item contained in the array.

```
$items = $elements['1af7e792-bcff-4a6c-9bdb-dd5023b0251a']['items'];
$sum = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $sum += $item['quantity'] * $item['price'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of flexibility, you want your code as portable as possible. I assume your id isn't always going to be `1af7e792-bcff-4a6c-9bdb-dd5023b0251a`, so you'll want to loop through the data that is returned.<sup>*`I don't know how you get the data, that's up to you.`*</sup>

So something like this, should gather the data you require and create an array:

```
$d = array();
foreach ($data as $id => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $values) {
        $d[$id][$key]['sum'] = $values['price'] * $values['quantity'];
    }
}

print_r($d);
```

<sup>**Note:** *The above code is untested*</sup>